# Databinding issue with class that is asynchronously updated

Tags: .net, data-binding, events

When I bind a `BindingList<ProcessDataItem>` to a `ComboBox` an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown saying, that the collection that is enumerated changed. Instances of `ProcessDataItem` permanently receive updates when their corresponding measurement value has changed. The class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify its container of those changes. This seems to cause the problem.
I'm surprised to have this issue since the collection remains untouched. Nothing is added or removed. Only values change. How can I fix this?

Edit:
The documentation of the `BindingList.ListChanged` event says:

> Occurs when the list or an item in the list changes.

This seems to cause my problem. Will I have to create an own container class that suppresses value change events while an enumeration is in progress?

Comment: The other problem to worry about is that these change events are probably coming from your background thread but being consumed by a GUI control, and interacting with a GUI control should only be done on the GUI thread. As such any object that raises events that are consumed by the GUI should only be modified on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to solve the synchronization issue in the `ProcessDataItem` class and not on container level. Now the `BindingList.ListChanged` event is called form the GUI thread. KeeperOfTheSoul was absolutely right with his comment.